# Electrician need to replace/inspect weather head and conduit?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, conduit

My weather head has always been broken and taped up. With a recent storm, the wires coming into my house broke off completely so I decided it was a good time to finally replace the weather head.

In the process, my neighbor came over and said it the wires need to be inspected before the electrical company can turn back on my power since the lines were hanked off. Is this true? Can I still replace the weather head myself and have the electrician just inspect the lines going into the electrical box from the weather head?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That line from the power company pole to your weatherhead is called the **service drop**.

The service drop is always energized.  There's no breaker or switch up on the pole. To de-energize a service drop, they have to come with a boom truck and go up there and detach each hot from the poletop splice.

So yes, the power company must be involved - that can't be avoided.

If you're saying all 3 wires have broken completely off your weatherhead and are laying in your lawn, then call the power company IMMEDIATELY since this is a downed power line that is energized, and can kill a kid.  They'll be out fast for that!

You have to check with your power company but usually they want to see proof of a city inspection/approval before energizing equipment.

So your project scope should be to replace the weatherhead.  Generally the city inspector won't make you replace a bunch of other stuff too.

If your circuit breaker panel is also as roached and old as that weatherhead, then **I very strongly suggest you also replace the electric meter with a "Meter-Main".**  Why?  Because this will let you fully de-energize the tired old main panel, which will open up a *whole bunch of options*... Some of those options enable DIY work, and other options enable doing the work in "small steps", which simplifies permitting requirements and doesn't require your house to lose power for more than an hour at a time.

Comment: I had this happen to my wife's rental property.  Storm broke a limb which pulled the service off the house.  Electric company refused to reconnect the drop until the service was replaced with new undamaged wire and passed by the town.  Found an electrician to do the work, then we had to find the town's inspector (on 3 day holiday weekend)  He poked around too.

Comment: The power was cut to the lines for my entire neighborhood and I verified with my electrical company that as long as the conduit was still attached to the house, I do not need the lines inspected. The lines broke off on the connectors between the street lines and my lines and nothing else was broken off. I have an older meter main still in place that works. I will consider adding a newer one in a near future and a generator plug as well for future storms.. :)